# Pandas - interpolate over values in index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I have the following Pandas dataframe:

```
       a0     a1      a2      a3
0.2  0.46  15.85  124.06 -380.04
0.4  0.21  28.20  -53.17   87.97
0.6  1.10  -5.55  167.76 -417.72
0.8  0.82   6.11   16.90  -70.86
1.0  1.00   0.00    0.00    0.00
```

Which is made by:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a0': [0.46,0.21,1.10,0.82,1],
                            'a1': [15.85,28.20,-5.55,6.11,0],
                            'a2': [124.06,-53.17,167.76,16.90,0],
                            'a3': [-380.04,87.97,-417.72,-70.86,0]},
                      index=pd.Series(['0.2', '0.4', '0.6','0.8','1.0']))
```

a0,a1,a2,a3 are polynomial coefficients from a fit y= a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 + a3*x^3.

5 fits have been made for 5 ratios Ht/H, these ratios are on the indices.

I want to return values for a0.. a3 for specified Ht/H ratio.

For example, if I specify Ht/H= 0.9, I want to get `a0= 0.91, a1= 3.05,a2= 8.45,a3= -35.43.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I notice that your index is currently strings, and you want numeric for interpolation. So do:

```
df.index = pd.to_numeric(df.index)
```

Let's try `reindex`:

```
s = 0.9

# create new index that includes the new value
new_idx = np.unique(list(df.index) + [s])

df.reindex(new_idx).interpolate('index').loc[s]
```

Output:

```
a0     0.910
a1     3.055
a2     8.450
a3   -35.430
Name: 0.9, dtype: float64
```